# return data type of Perl regex matching groups

Tags: regex, perl

I've got a question about the handling/ return data type of a regex matching multiple groups.
Consider this line:

```
($pre, $middle, $post) = $text =~ /(.*)Telefon:(.+)(Fax:.*)/;
```

It assigns the values of matched parts of $text to $pre, $middle and $post **as a list**, I suppose!
So I would like to check before the number of returned matches. Since the returned data type is a list, i assume that the following works:

```
if (scalar ($text =~ /(.*)Telefon:(.+)(Fax:.*)/) == 3) { do something }
```

The problem seems to be that

```
(scalar ($text =~ /(.*)Telefon:(.+)(Fax:.*)/)
```

returns `1`, **although the following works as expected** (returning the value `3`):

```
my @arr = $text =~ /(.*)Telefon:(.+)(Fax:.*)/;
scalar @arr
```

There seems to be some Perl magic going on. What can I do to get the expected value without assigning a value (`@arr`) in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to supply list context for the match – e.g. by assigning to a list:

```
() = $text =~ /.../
```

Yes, the empty list works. We can the use this list assignment in a scalar context, e.g.

```
3 == (() = $text =~ /.../)
```

You can think of `()=` as a “count of” pseudo-operator.

The behavior of many Perl operators and builtins differ depending on context. If in doubt, read the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators) (although this specific section refers you to other parts of the docs).

Answer (score 4):

In perl, a function or operator can return different things in scalar context compared to list context. In fact even subs you write yourself can do this .. See the wantarray keyword.

When a regex is evaluated in scalar context it returns 1 for a match or 0 for no match. Different to what it returns in list context, which is the capture groups.

When you assign to an array first, the regex is evaluated in list context. Then you take the scalar value of the array, which gives the length.

In any case I suspect you are not going to get the result you want. If the regex matches you will always get a list of size 3, even if some of the capture groups are empty. However if any of the capture groups are empty then the resulting slots in the list will be undef (which you can check for). If the regex did not match then you get an empty list back.